# How to count multiple items in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have the following list:

```
data = [[2004,1,1,1,50], [2008,2,28,1,150],[1984,5,1,3,20],[1982,5,1,7,20], [1982,5,8,7,20]]
```

The data represents the Year, Month, Day, Day of week, count.

I want to obtain a dictionary of the total counts per day of the week. Something like this

```
results = {1:200,
           2:0,
           3:20,
           4:0,
           5:0,
           6:0,
           7:40,
}
```

I believe the best way to do this, please correct me if i'm wrong, is to use collections.Counter. I abandoned this effort for a dictionary comprehension but have been unable to solve the problem

```
solution = {(x,i) for x[3], i[4] in data}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to sum and not count it might be easier to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[2004,1,1,1,50], [2008,2,30,1,150],[1984,5,1,3,20],[1982,5,1,7,20], [1982,5,8,7,20]]

c = defaultdict(int)

for l in data:
    c[l[3]] += l[4]

print(c)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 3: 20, 7: 40})
```

If you insist on having zero entries you can instantiate it before:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [[2004,1,1,1,50], [2008,2,30,1,150],[1984,5,1,3,20],[1982,5,1,7,20], [1982,5,8,7,20]]

c = defaultdict(int)
c.update({d: 0 for d in range(1, 8)})
for l in data:
    c[l[3]] += l[4]
print(c)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 2: 0, 3: 20, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 40})
```

At this point you may use a normal dict over `defaultdict` if you are sure that the input will not have invalid days:

```
data = [[2004,1,1,1,50], [2008,2,30,1,150],[1984,5,1,3,20],[1982,5,1,7,20], [1982,5,8,7,20]]

c = {d: 0 for d in range(1, 8)} # or dict.fromkeys(range(1, 8), 0)
for l in data:
    c[l[3]] += l[4]
print(c)
# {1: 200, 2: 0, 3: 20, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 40}
```

Comment: Just to note that you can create `c` here without a `dict-comp`, eg: `c = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 8), 0)`...

Answer (score 1):

If, as in your input data, your `data` is sorted by day of week, i.e. all sublists for a particular day of week are adjacent to each other, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = {k: sum(map(itemgetter(-1), v)) for k, v in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(-2))}

print(res)
# {1: 200, 3: 20, 7: 40}
```

If your data is not sorted, you will have to sort by day of week *first*:

```
data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this problem with a simple loop instead. Create a results dict with initial values for each day set to zero, and just add to it step  by step.

```
results = {k:0 for k in range(1,8)}
#Output: {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}
data = [[2004,1,1,1,50], [2008,2,30,1,150],[1984,5,1,3,20],[1982,5,1,7,20], [1982,5,8,7,20]]

for x in data:
    results[x[3]] += x[4]

print(results)
#Output:
{1: 200, 2: 0, 3: 20, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 40}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked to use Counter from collections, you could use it like this:

```
from collections import Counter

counter=Counter()

for group in data:
    counter[group[3]] +=group[4]

results=dict(counter)
```

Comment: nice, but `Counter` already subclasses `dict`, no need to `dict(counter)`

Comment: Can you tell me why something like this wouldnt work, but yours does? 

import collections \n for item in data: \n collections.Counter[item[3] +=item[4]

Comment: collections.Counter is a class. You need an instance of this class and use the instance: "counter=collections.Counter()". As DeepSpace mentioned, Counter is a subclass of dict and so you can use the brackets to add key-value pairs: counter[key] = value.